# Chain Rule in Multiple Dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Let $x$ be a map, $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $V$ be a map, $V:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Then the derivative
$$\dfrac{d}{dt}V(x(t))=\nabla V(x(t))\cdot x'(t)=\langle\ \nabla V(x(t)),\ x'(t)\ \rangle$$
is the above inner product. However, I am stuck on understanding the first equality. The analogy to the "standard case" where $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x),f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is clear, but I would appreciate a slightly more rigorous derivation where the dot product becomes more clear.

Edit: I'm thinking it would be most understandable to me if we could use something like $\dfrac{d}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{d\text{something}}\dfrac{d\text{something}}{dt}$ to make the derivative of $V$ clearer.

Comment: The Jacobian matrixderivative of a composition is the  product of the Jacobian matrices of each ‘factor’ of the composition. Just plain linear algebra.

Comment: @Bernard can you explain the Jacobian matrices more? I've taken linear algebra and this didn't come up.

Comment: It is the standard matrix representation J of the linear map that approximates the Way your function g:R^m—>R^n changes at a point. It has entries given by: J_ij=dg_i/dxj. Where g_i is the i’th coordinate function of g and x1,...xm are your coordinates on R^m. See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant for more info.

Comment: Do you know that the derivative, in this context, is a linear transformation? The chain rule expresses the derivative of a composition as the composition of derivatives: $(V\circ x)'(t)=V'(x(t))\circ x'(t)$. If you write this as a product of matrices with respect to the standard bases, you will get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple case first:

One way to "derive" the chain rule for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dx}f(g(x))&=\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}\dfrac{d}{dg(x)}f(g(x))\\
&=\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx}\dfrac{df(g(x))}{dg(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{dg(x)}{dx} \dfrac{df(u)}{du}\biggr\rvert_{u=g(x)}\\
&=g'(x)f'(g(x))
\end{align}$$

Where I have tried to make it obvious that differentiating a function by its argument is *then* evaluated at the same argument.

So for this question:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dt}V(x(t))
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}
\bigg(\dfrac{dx_1(t)}{dt}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1(t)}+\cdots+\dfrac{dx_n(t)}{dt}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n(t)}\bigg)V(x(t))\\
&=
\dfrac{dx(t)}{dt}\cdot
\bigg(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1(t)},\dots,\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n(t)}\bigg)V(x(t))\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}
x'(t)\cdot
\nabla V(x(t))\\
\end{align}$$

where in $(2)$ we analogously take the "standard" gradient of $V$, then evaluate at $x(t)$. This is because when we distribute $V$ into the vector of partial derivatives, we get $\dfrac{\partial V(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial x_i}$, which is a derivative with respect to the $i$th variable then evaluated at $x(t)$.

And in $(1)$ we are rewriting the total derivative in terms of a sum of partial derivatives of all the variables relevant to $V(x)$, the function we wish to differentiate in a standard way (i.e. derivatives with respect to its arguments). That is,

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}=\dfrac{dx_1}{dt}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+\cdots+\dfrac{dx_n}{dt}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$$